# classes detected in LinearSVC only supports binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I get the following error when I type the code here.

```
   rf = LinearSVC(labelCol="indexedLabel", maxIter=10, regParam=0.1)
   pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[self.labelIndexer, self.featureIndexer, rf, 
   self.labelConverter])
   model = pipeline.fit(self.trainingData)

IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: LinearSVC only supports binary classification. 99 classes detected in LinearSVC_6596220b55a3__labelCol'
```

Comment: So, what is your *question*? Spark `LinearSVC` is only suitable for binary classification, as explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=model#pyspark.ml.classification.LinearSVC).

Comment: ie 1 and 0, or true and false?

Comment: I want to use the Support Vector Machine (SVM). But I have 99 classes. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: 1) I would *definitely* go with `0/1` - see https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-classification/ 2) Do you *really* need to use Spark? Do you really have data that cannot fit into a single machine, and need a *cluster*? If not, you don't really need Spark...

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I used "Logistic Regression", "Naive Bayes", "Random Forest Classifier", "Decision Tree Classifier" because they support MultiClass. But I need to use the SVM and KNN algorithms. I wonder how I can solve this.

Comment: You didn't answer my crucial question: *why pyspark*, and not, say, scikit-learn?

Comment: PySpark provides faster solutions for large data processing. The data I have is too big. That's why I have to use PySpark on Python. I also get help from the scikit-learn library in some cases.